# Why are SSRS 2008 reports taking longer through ReportViewer control?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

There are a couple reports which stopped working, and I'm getting an error "An Existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."  When I try to look at the reports they are taking forever to run, and in the event log there were a couple timeout errors... so guessing I'm getting that error due to timeout.

Now the problem is figuring out why the reports are running so slow.  I already changed the proc to prevent parameter sniffing... but basically:

Run the proc through SSMS:  1:42
Run the report through Report Server:  6:45
Run report through ASP.NET ReportViewer control:  13:00 minutes

So the real mystery here for me is why it's twice as slow through the ReportViewer control as through SSRS itself?  (I can deal with the report being slower than the proc later...)

EDIT:

Ran some profiling as suggested in the comments.  The stored procedure is running at normal speed (55 seconds) when being called from the report itself. So the problem is either the SSRS server, the ReportViewer control, both... or the network between the ReportViewer and the SSRS server.

Also if I run the report on my desktop PC (over VPN) in Visual Studio it works just fine.

Also, there are some other shorter reports that are running just fine.  Wondering if it's just they pull so much less data though.

One last thing I've noticed is that the query seems to be running multiple times when run through the ReportViewer control.

EDIT Again:

Looked at the ExecutionLog tables, and the time is definitely going to *rendering* the report.  The time for getting the data is pretty consistent.  Also the rendering takes 6 minutes longer on the production server than the test server (even running the query against the production database) so it's definitely something with Reporting Services.

Comment: Is ReportViewer set to Local or Remote processing mode?

Comment: Remote processing mode...

Comment: And you're sure stored proc is the bottleneck - did you run a trace? Also, what did you do for parameter sniffing - did you add WITH RECOMPILE?

Comment: I don't think the proc is the bottleneck, it's slow but the report is doubling the time, and the ReportViewer is doubling it again.  I copied the parameters into local variables for the parameter sniffing.  Did not use recompile.  Not sure what tracing I would do...?

Comment: Also I did run sp_recompile on the proc after I made the changes...

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler to run a trace to see exactly how long SP takes to run during report generation. As for the second - try altering your SP by adding `WITH RECOMPILE` before 'AS' like here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/20/sql-server-recompile-stored-procedure-at-run-time/

Comment: OK added some info after running the profiler... also add the WITH RECOMPILE.

Answer (score -1):

It's a shot in the dark, but whenever we run into this problem one of the first things that we do is drop statistics on the tables involved, and let the DBMS recreate them as needed. We have noticed that WITH RECOMPILE does not seem to help as well.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the query though, verified that with the profiler.  Query is taking 55 seconds to run but the report is taking 6 minutes to render.